# "no command" after OTA update of a Wiko Rainbow 4G

Tags: unbricking

My son has a [Wiko Rainbow 4G](http://fr.wikomobile.com/m368-RAINBOW-4G) (a French company) which underwent an OTA update. It runs by default Kitkat 4.4. The phone was not rooted not modified in any way.

After the OTA the phone rebooted but is now stuck in a "no command" ("pas de commande" in French) state - the image is of the green Android character laying on the ground with its "front panel" open and an exclamation mark.

I tried to [reinstall the stock ROM](http://fr.wikomobile.com/update-368-RAINBOW-4G) but the phone is not recognized by the update program (<del>despite having correct drivers installed</del> **it turns out I was wrong**, see [my answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/135143/25245) below).

I have access to recovery mode and could attempt to flash a ROM but the flashable version (a zip) is not available. I tried to do a factory restet from the recovery mode - it worked but the problem is the same.

Is there something else I should try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It turned out that the drivers which were installed on my Windows machine were not good enough for flashing.** They were OK for normal connection when the phone was working.

I found the correct drivers on the [GSM USB DRIVER](http://gsmusbdriver.com/wiko-rainbow-4g) site. I installed the VCOM version by going into `Device Manager`, clicking on the computer (upper-most entry) and selecting `Action -> Add legacy software`.

The installation failed. So that it goes though the PC needs to be restarted in a mode which allows for non-signed drivers. This is explained in a [good video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z6HbmjXONuk), the steps are to reboot your PC by shift clicking the reboot entry, then `Troubleshoot`, `Advanced options`, `Startup settings`, `Disable signed drivers enforcement`. After the automatic reboot the installation above will succeed, and then the flashing does so as well.

All credit goes to [Android MTK](http://androidmtk.com/) for the tutorials and [GSM USB DRIVER](http://gsmusbdriver.com/) for the drivers.